# Printing Objects in Stack [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, stack

So the project is to make a deck of cards, create methods to shuffle and deal the cards and compare.

Not even going that far, I'm having an issue displaying the contents of the Stack.

I'm getting the output `randomdeck.Card@10ed7f5c` but with different addresses for every card.

I did a size check and there are 52 objects in the stack, meaning I filled it and it actually exists.

Looking at my Card constructor I know I'm not actually filling it with the cSuit/cRank String array. My original code had it so I would fill it with the integers then have a method to read those integers and put those integers into a the String arrays displaying the String.

But I had to partially scrap that because it was just an array, not a Stack.

If there was a way to directly pass the String array into the Card so what it's pushed into the Deck I could pop it off and instantly see the contents that would be great. But I fear that's not possible and I'm failing to grasp something fundamental about Stacks/Queues.

I wish I kept my old code completely intact to show what I was previously doing, but I don't think it matters at this point.

Here is my current code.

```
package randomdeck;
//import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Card 
{
int Suit;
int Rank;


public Card(int Rank, int Suit)
{
    this.Suit=Suit;
    this.Rank=Rank;
}


public  String[] cSuit = new String[4];
{
    cSuit[0]="Hearts";
    cSuit[1]="Spades";
    cSuit[2]="Diamonds";
    cSuit[3]="Clubs";
}

public  String[] cRank = new String[13];
{
    cRank[0]="Ace";
    cRank[1]="2";
    cRank[2]="3";
    cRank[3]="4";
    cRank[4]="5";
    cRank[5]="6";
    cRank[6]="7";
    cRank[7]="8";
    cRank[8]="9";
    cRank[9]="10";
    cRank[10]="Jack";
    cRank[11]="Queen";
    cRank[12]="King";
}

void displayCard()
{
    //System.out.println(cRank + " Of " + cSuit);
    System.out.println(cRank[Rank] + " of " + cSuit[Suit]);
}


}
```

Here is the Deck class

```
package randomdeck;
//import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Deck 
{
int cardNum=0;
//static int DeckSize=52;
Stack<Card> Deck = new Stack<Card>();


public Deck()
{

   for(int rank=0; rank<13; rank++)
   {
       for(int suit=0; suit<4; suit++)
       {
           Deck.push(new Card(rank,suit));
           System.out.println(Deck.peek());
           //System.out.println(Deck.size());
           //Deck[cardNum] = new Card(rank,suit);
           //cardNum++;
       }
   }
}


public void Peek()
{
   System.out.println(Deck.peek());

}

public void Size()
{
   System.out.println(Deck.size());
}
}
```

Here is the last class

```
package randomdeck;
//import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Stack;

public class RandomDeck {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Deck testDeck= new Deck();
    testDeck.Size();

}

}
```

Comment: Look into the `toString()` method of the `Object` class. Array types do not override that method.

Comment: Please, *please* follow proper naming conventions. Not doing so makes this hard to read. Variables should not be uppercase (you have a variable and a class with the same name)

Comment: Yea, I know I goofed on that. I've been away from java for nearly a month, it takes a while for stupid things to get out of my head. Will be renaming variables to appropriate conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to add a `toString()` method to your `Card` class like so,

```
public String toString() {
  return cRank[Rank] + " of " + cSuit[Suit];
}
```

Also, I think you should rename `Rank` and `Suit` to `rank` and `suit` respectively.

Finally, a more idiomatic String array initialization would be

```
public String[] cSuit = new String[] { "Hearts",
    "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };

public String[] cRank = new String[] { "Ace", "2",
    "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack",
    "Queen", "King" };
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks, and I fixed the variable names, forgot I shouldn't capitalize variables like that.